# Why does sorting by DPS in the Auction House not always correctly sort?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was browsing the auction house for a new 1 handed crossbow and decided to sort by DPS, clicking on the DPS and getting the arrow pointed in the right direction.

To my surprise I noticed several of the entries were out of order.  Page 2 had weapons with more DPS than page 1.  After the first couple of pages however, things seemed to be correct, overall.

Does the auction house use some method other than DPS to sort when I sort by DPS (ie is it considering a speed increase or some other factor)?

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could post a screenshot of it? I have never had any issues with it so I'm curious to see.

Comment: @BcnGehrke Done

Comment: Most likely it's sorting by *base* damage.  It's not including the extra dps provided by affixes, such as +*elemental* damage.

Comment: I've noticed that sorting can definitely go wonky if you sort by something else (like, say, buyout price) and then later try to sort by DPS.

Comment: @Sterno The screen shot was generated by logging in and going straight to the auction house with only clicking sort by dps

Comment: @Stephen I'm not saying that my method is the **only** way of screwing it up. :)

Comment: The "sort by dps" just doesn't work sometimes. I don't know why. It is not sorting by base dps or anything because when you try and change the order, ie looking for the lowest instead of highest dps, the list stays in the same order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally in game when you socket a ruby into a weapon it will update the displayed DPS to account for the increased damage but in the AH when people post weapons already socketed with rubies it is not updating the tooltip. The sort by dps does seem to be taking the socketed ruby into account though.

Comment: If thats the case then its a `bug` and should be reported.  There are ways to verify this :-)

Comment: also, sorting by dps doesn't work when you are searching for a legendary